# Multivariate optimisation with sum and integer constraints

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, scipy-optimize

I want to optimize a function
X-> list of 50 variables
Y-> list of 50 variables

```
alpha1=3
alpha2=4
beta = 5

def objective(X,Y):
    y_ = alpha1*pd.Series(X)+alpha2*pd.Series(Y)+beta
    return mean_squared_error(y_,df.demand)
```

Where constraints are

1. each element of X,Y are integer
2. Sum(X) = 100 and Sum(Y) = 100

The output should be total of 100 values ( 50 X, 50 Y ) minimizing the objective function.

Comment: What is your question? Note also that providing a minimal **reproducible** example will increase your chances of getting helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the below solution. I have used Google-ortool's CP-SAT solver.
I am minimizing total sum of squares instead of mean squared of errors, but it will not impact the final solution : X's and Y's values

```
import random
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model as cp

alpha1=3
alpha2=4
beta = 5

demand = [random.randint(0, 50) for _ in range(50)]

dv_x = {}
dv_y = {}
dv_y_ = {}
dv_diff_y_and_demand = {}
dv_diff_y_and_demand_abs = {}
dv_diff_y_and_demand_sqr = {}

model = cp.CpModel()

for i in range(50):
    dv_x[i] = model.NewIntVar(0, 50, "")
    dv_y[i] = model.NewIntVar(0, 50, "")
    dv_y_[i] = model.NewIntVar(0, 10000, "")
    dv_diff_y_and_demand[i] = model.NewIntVar(-10000, 10000, "")
    dv_diff_y_and_demand_sqr[i] = model.NewIntVar(0, 10000, "")
    dv_diff_y_and_demand_abs[i] = model.NewIntVar(0, 10000, "")
    
    model.Add(dv_y_[i] == alpha1*dv_x[i] + alpha2*dv_y[i] + beta)
    
    model.Add(dv_diff_y_and_demand[i] == dv_y_[i] - demand[i])
    model.AddAbsEquality(dv_diff_y_and_demand_abs[i], dv_diff_y_and_demand[i])
    
    model.AddMultiplicationEquality(dv_diff_y_and_demand_sqr[i], [dv_diff_y_and_demand_abs[i], dv_diff_y_and_demand_abs[i]])

model.Add(sum(dv_x[i] for i in range(50)) == 100)
model.Add(sum(dv_y[i] for i in range(50)) == 100)

total_squared_error = model.NewIntVar(0, 100000, "")

model.Add(total_squared_error == sum(dv_diff_y_and_demand_sqr[i] for i in range(50)))

model.Minimize(total_squared_error)

solver = cp.CpSolver()
solver.parameters.num_search_workers = 8   # using 8 VCPUs
solver.Solve(model)

# mean squared error
solver.ObjectiveValue()
# inspect decision variable values
[solver.Value(dv_x[i]) for i in range(50)]
[solver.Value(dv_y[i]) for i in range(50)]
```